# how to make dynamically loaded image with different width and height responsive in css

Tags: html, css, image-scaling

I load images dynamically into my webpage and make them responsive:

```
<div id="images"><img id="dynamic_img" src=""/></div>
```

css:

```
#images{
  height: 80%;
  width: 30%

}

img{
     max-height: auto 
      max-width:100%
}
```

Problem now is, that the images have different heights and widths. Now this works when the width of an image is longer than its height but not the other way around. (in this case `max-height` would be 100% and `max-width: auto`

Is this possible to switch these two values according to the image loaded in  CSS or do I need to use JS for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an example where images are fitted horizontal and vertically.

I used

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Here you are: https://jsfiddle.net/jormaechea/j219ucnc/1/

---

#### Update

The key to achieve this is to set

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: if I use this, it works for all the img in the page that are preloaded but the ones that get loaded dynamically still look squeezed when I change the height

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="images"><img class="img" src="" alt="" /></div>

.img
{
    width=100%;
}
```

your div should have width=100% for example.

don't use max-width

you can set the #images div also a with of 80% - it will be responsive and the image refits to the divs width

Comment: ok so that works for images with `width > height` . If I have an image with `height>width` the image will be bigger than the div (`div id="images"` has a fixed width and height). I want the image to be the same size as the div or smaller, not bigger

Comment: Just realized i wasn't precise in my question i edited the text sorry!

Comment: alright. you can set the background-image of the div instead. see: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Comment: ah.. you found a working solution in the meantime. to answer your question.. didn't take this dynamicaly thing into account (mea culpa) and would have to test. first idea would be to determine width and height of image and set appropriate css (using php/template-engine or js) - sounds a bit complicated ;-)